# Search documents & display results in snippet view like Google books?

Tags: search, search-engine, pdf-viewer, text-search, file-search

I'm looking for any software that can search keywords in documents (at least text files, but hopefully PDFs) in a folder (or even within a single file) and **show the result in snippet view** like Google Books (search "From inside the book").

Do you know anything about this?

[image: Google Books - from inside the book]

Comment: What OS, free or commercial?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to recommend AstroGrep which has a very similar layout to the Google Snippet view.  It supports plain text files.  It is based of the UNIX utility "grep" and is completely free to use.  It also contains a numerous amount of options as well for searching.

## [AstroGrep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyOxH.png) (free)

> AstroGrep is a Microsoft Windows grep utility. Grep is a UNIX command-line program which searches within files for keywords. AstroGrep supports regular expressions, versatile printing options, stores most recently used paths and has a "context" feature which is very nice for looking at source code.

Here's a screenshot of it in action:

[image: screenshot]