# Need file database that can search file filenames, metadata, and text content (e.g. PDFs)

Tags: file-management, search-engine, file-search

I am looking to build a database of many files including PDF, XLSS, text, image, and other file formats. I need a way to search these files for content and metadata, while providing easy access to the file itself.

The way this would be used is I would, for example, want to find any PDFs that contained a certain phrase or keywords, and I want to be able to search for that phrase and see a list of all the files that match, along with a snippet of the matching text, and where you can click directly on the result to open the file (or download it if the system is hosted remotely). Essentially like a web search engine but for local files.

I am fine doing some development to ensure this has all of the features I need, but I don't want to reinvent any wheels. I have been exploring Elasticsearch but I am not sure if that is the route I should be going down or not.

[This question's answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36301/search-documents-display-results-in-snippet-view-like-google-books) is an incredibly minimalist version of what I want, but I am hoping to find something closer to a database that can support the easy addition of metadata and offers clear delineation between metadata, content, and filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you also have a look at [Recoll](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) if you have not already done so.

It caters for many file types, etc. it also runs on Windows, Linux, Mac OSX. You can also extend it if necessary.

edit:
Also take a look at https://github.com/simon987/sist2

Comment: Recoll seems to be what I need. sist2 looks promising as well but it's a bit early in its development stages right now. Good to know about though! Thanks!